# Simultaneous eqns in maple

Tags: maple

I am trying to solve the following system of equations in maple but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
solve({
a*(1-x)-x*f-x*e = 0, 
b*(1-x)-x*c-x*d = 0, 
c*(1-z)-z*b-z*a = 0, 
d*(1-z)-z*e-z*f = 0, 
e*(1-y)-y*d-y*c = 0, 
f*(1-y)-y*a-y*b = 0, 
a+b+c+d+e+f-1 = 0 },
{a, b, c, d, e, f
})
```

Comment: I tried just now and for me, no answers in outputs, so, no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This linear system of equations is inconsistent. One way to see this is to recognize that the first 6 equations imply that the variables `a` to `f` all have value zero. But the last equation dictates that their sum is equal to 1. Clearly, if they are all zero then they cannot add up to 1.

```
eqs:=[a*(1-x)-x*f-x*e = 0, 
  b*(1-x)-x*c-x*d = 0, 
  c*(1-z)-z*b-z*a = 0, 
  d*(1-z)-z*e-z*f = 0, 
  e*(1-y)-y*d-y*c = 0, 
  f*(1-y)-y*a-y*b = 0, 
  a+b+c+d+e+f-1 = 0]:

vars:=[a, b, c, d, e, f]:

with(LinearAlgebra):
```

Now compare results from

```
linsys:=GenerateMatrix(eqs[1..6],vars,augmented);
LinearSolve(linsys);

LUDecomposition(GenerateMatrix(eqs[1..6],vars,augmented),output=R);
%[1..-1,1..6].Vector(vars)=%[1..-1,7];
```

with that from,

```
linsys:=GenerateMatrix(eqs,vars,augmented);
LinearSolve(linsys);

LUDecomposition(GenerateMatrix(eqs,vars,augmented),output=R);
%[1..-1,1..6].Vector(vars)=%[1..-1,7];
```

Answer (score 0):

The equations look linear in $a,b,c,d,e,f$. As such, you can use
$$A,b:=LinearAlgebra[GenerateMatrix](system\_of\_equations,variables);$$
and then $LinearAlgebra[LinearSolve](A,b)$ to solve the matrix system.